# php login not working

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

i have a mysql table with the following fields:

id
username
password
role

the admin has a role number 1 and a normal user has a role number 2

```
    <?php
// we must never forget to start the session
session_start();

$errorMessage = '';
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    include 'library/connect.php';

    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if the user id and password combination exist in database
    $sql = "SELECT role FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error()); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 AND $row['role']==2) {
        // the user id and password match, 
        // set the session
        $_SESSION['userame'] = true;
        // after login we move to the main page
        header('Location: login_success.php');
        exit;
    }
    elseif (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 AND $row['role']== 1) {
        // the user id and password match, 
        // set the session
        $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = true;
        // after login we move to the main page
        header('Location: admin.php');
        exit;
    }
else {
        $errorMessage = 'Sorry, wrong user id / password <a href="login.html">Go Back</a>';
    }

    include 'library/closedb.php';
}
?>



<?php
if ($errorMessage != '') {
?>
<p align="center"><strong><font color="#990000"><?php echo $errorMessage; ?></font></strong></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

When an admin logs in, it works fine and gets redirected to admin.php whereas when a normal user logs in, nothing happens at all, the page just gets refreshed. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: **WARNING** This code is susceptible to **[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**.

Comment: i know, not focused on secuirty atm

Comment: Is this a typo here or in your code? `$_SESSION['userame'] = true;` shouldn't it be $_SESSION['username']?

Comment: Do you get any error messages, and have you confirmed the login details for the non-admin user? Also you should encrypt your passwords!

Comment: @DamienPirsy whats that mean? sorry im new to php

Comment: @DamienPirsy thanks, that was the error

Answer (score 6):

you misspelled username in the first `if` block for `role=2`

`$_SESSION['userame'] = true;`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a typo is the cause:

```
$_SESSION['userame'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $_SESSION['userame'] = true;
 to
 $_SESSION['username'] = true;
```

if it dont fix problem can you give login_success.php

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 AND $row['role']==2) {
        // the user id and password match, 
        // set the session
        $_SESSION['username'] = true;
        // after login we move to the main page
        header('Location: login_success.php');
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, its first day and first response almost impossible